# How to test submitting json/data with Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

How to test form data/json sending to the server using Cypress?

I tried next approach:

```
    it('Stored value is correct on submission', () => {
        cy.server();
        cy.route({
          method: 'POST',
          url: `/app/api/data/${formId}/${modelId}`,
          onRequest: (e) => {
            cy.get('@formPOST').should('deep.equal', expectedRequestBody);
          }
        });
        cy.get("button[type='submit']").click({force: true});
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked for a quick solution to intercept and test data send from my form but haven't found any, so i share my experience :

```
describe('Submitted data is correct', () => {
      it('Stored and empty values are send as expected', () => {
        cy.server();
        cy.route('POST', `/app/api/data/${formId}`).as('formPOST');
        cy.get("button[type='submit']").click({force: true});
        cy.wait('@formPOST')
          .its('requestBody')
          .should('deep.equal', expectedRequestBody)
      });
    });
```

Note that the expected data to be submitted is in variable *expectedRequestBody*.
The most interesting and uncleaer that Cypress compares submitted data event after the redirection